# Why printf help to prevent segmentation fault in this following code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_CHARS 256

typedef struct Frequency Frequency;
struct Frequency {
  // Frequency value:
  int  v;
};

typedef struct Context Context;
struct Context {
  Frequency table[NUMBER_OF_CHARS];
};

int main(){
Context* x;
(x->table[0]).v=10;
//printf("%d\n",(x->table[0]).v);
}
```

If I comment out printf, I run the program then I get segmentation fault; If I run the program with printf then I will get the value 10. Why it happends?

Comment: You use `->` on an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Accessing an unitialized pointer is undefined behavior. Anything could happen.

Comment: The above should be read as: **Anything** *could* happen.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the above comments, you are using the x variable which is a pointer and is not allocated. You can use the following:

```
int main(){
    Context x; // you are allocated on the stack a Context value
    x.table[0].v=10; // set the Frequency of first item
    //printf("%d\n",(x.table[0].v);
    return (0);
}
```

Instead of :

```
int main(){
    Context* x;
    (x->table[0]).v=10;
    //printf("%d\n",(x->table[0]).v);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can I do Context*x =malloc(sizeof(Context)), and then doing                   (x->table[0]).v=10 ?

Comment: @QiqinZhao no problem to use `Context*x =malloc(sizeof(Context));`, but don't forget to add `free(x);` after using this pointer.